# move stdout out of the console, in portable C

Tags: c, linux, windows, console-application, stdout

The target application can be used in "pipe" mode, which means it accepts input from stdin, and can output into stdout.

However, there is always a risk of a user making a mistake, directing output to stdout, without actually directing stdout towards "something" (a file, or a consumer program).
As a consequence, the console screen gets garbaged displaying binary data (since by default, stdout outputs to the screen).

Bottom line : I want to avoid binary output to be displayed into the console, automatically. It must be done in **portable C**, and not depend on external script.

A few potential ways of doing it :

1) Is it possible to detect that stdout is going to console, in order to redirect it somewhere else instead ? (including /dev/nul). Note that the code *must* be portable, and work for Windows and Linux (and BSD, OpenSolaris, etc.)

2) Alternative : is it possible to redirect stdout to "somewhere else" (such as /dev/nul) by default without actually harming a correct usage of the program, redirecting stdout to a valid consumer process ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a POSIX (e.g. Linux and OSX) system you can use the [`isatty`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isatty.html) function to check if `stdout` goes to a console or to something else:

```
if (isatty(STDOUT_FILENO))
    printf("Going to a console\n");
else
    printf("Standard output is redirected or piped\n");
```

---

Unfortunately there is no portable way to do this that works on both POSIX systems and Windows.

Comment: Wow, thanks, that looks a fine direction. Unfortunately, portability is a strong requirement. Could _isatty() do the trick there ?

Comment: I was going to talk about programmatically doing stdout redirections, but I think they are unix only. Dang

Comment: @Cyan It might, but I really don't know.

Comment: @ClydeByrdIII: `freopen()` can be used to programmitically redirect `stdout` in standard C.

Comment: @jxh why am I tagged? I was going to talk about dup and dup2. Which are non-portable if I'm not mistaken.